# RxJava - zip list of Observable if throw exception how to get success response

Tags: java, android, kotlin, observable, rx-java

I am trying to call multiple API parallel using rxjava2 in Android. it's working as per the requirement but in case of any api throws exception it fails to give the response of other API's, so is there any way to call other API who returning success response.

```
private fun getStoreCouponData() {

    val userObservable = repo2
        .create<StoreCouponsApi>(StoreCouponsApi::class.java!!)
        .getCoupons
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    val eventsObservable = repo2
        .create<StoreCouponsApi>(StoreCouponsApi::class.java!!)
        .storeInfo
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    val combined = Observable.zip<StoreCoupons, StoreCoupons, StoreList>(userObservable, eventsObservable,
        BiFunction<StoreCoupons, StoreCoupons, StoreList> { response1, response2 -> StoreList(response1, response2) })

    combined.subscribe(object : DefaultObserver<StoreList>() {
        override fun onNext(s: StoreList) {
            for (item in s.store!!.coupons!!) {
                System.out.println(item.store)
            }
        }


        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
           System.out.println(e)
        }

        override fun onComplete() {

        }
    })

    println(combined)

}
```

Comment: How would you right unit test to this method? Try to make your life less painful.

Comment: @The_Martian its POC only.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is callback called `onErrorResumeNext` which can be used for continuing the process, when one request gets to error.

```
val combined = Observable.zip<StoreCoupons, StoreCoupons, StoreList>(userObservable, eventsObservable,
        BiFunction<StoreCoupons, StoreCoupons, StoreList> { response1, response2 -> StoreList(response1, response2) }).onErrorResumeNext(
// you can error separately on each requests, and you can call other requests )
```

Comment: This works too but I wonder if there is a cleaner way :thinking:

Comment: I think this is the correct way to do it, otherwise you've to do some crazy hack ideas @Bach Vu

Comment: @Manoj i have added like this combined.onErrorResumeNext{ throwable: Throwable ->
            System.out.println("hello i am "+ throwable)
            Observable.empty<StoreList>()

        }
but its not working.. still its going onError method only. Thanks

Comment: @Raj try .onErrorResumeNext( Observable.empty())

Comment: @Manoj i added your code but still its going onError only.. i am trying to get success api response and fail exception also. but i am getting exception only.

Comment: @Raj there are `onExceptionResumeNext` and `onErrorResumeNext`, you should pass empty osbervable in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194154/discussion-between-raj-and-manoj-perumarath).